# Go back to previous fragment but not previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an Activity (A), that launch an other (B), in this activity (B) I have some fragments.
When I press back on my activity B it's going correctly to the previous fragments, but when I click on back on the last fragment in the stack, it returns to the previous activity.

How can I do to not returning to the previous activity at the end ?
(And also quit the app instead)

Comment: You might want to post your code.

Comment: Simply replace the current Fragment with the old one.

Comment: Everything is actually working, but when I press back too many times it goes back to the previous activity (because there is no more fragment in the backstack) and I want to avoid that

Comment: This question may contain all info you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482606/when-a-fragment-is-replaced-and-put-in-the-back-stack-or-removed-does-it-stay

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your `FragmentTransaction`'s `addToBackStack(String name)` method? As in:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("NewFragment")
```