# android - glide bitmaps not being GC'd

Tags: android, bitmap, garbage-collection, android-glide

Our app has the ability to chain navigation together, which is resulting in us running out of memory.

By chaining I mean we have one Activity, and a certain type of Fragment that allows you to open an instance of the same fragment type but with diff data.

e.g. Activity->MyFragment->MyFragment->MyFragment->MyFragment->MyFragment....

because of this we run out of memory eventually as this fragment has a viewpager of images plus another few images in it.

looking at the following two SO links

[Android app out of memory issues - tried everything and still at a loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536988/android-app-out-of-memory-issues-tried-everything-and-still-at-a-loss)

[When a Fragment is replaced and put in the back stack (or removed) does it stay in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482606/when-a-fragment-is-replaced-and-put-in-the-back-stack-or-removed-does-it-stay)

Diane (hackbod) highlights that you should tidy up your resources in onDestroyView, which I have done.

However, using the Memory tab in Android Monitor, and dumping the heap to hprof files, I can see that my bitmaps and imageviews never get destroyed.

I am wondering if this is something to do with Glide and the bitmapPool?  I don't know how to configure this as we are only using the static Gilde.with method to get a RequestManager and I can't see any methods in that to configure bitmapPools or anything.

Any ideas?

:)